# How to set custom property on ics calendar invite

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar, invite

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:GMT
BEGIN:STANDARD
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=test@abc.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@abc.com
ATTENDEE;CN=test@abc.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@abc.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20220916T003527
DESCRIPTION:test custom property in email.
DTEND;TZID=GMT:20110420T093502
DTSTAMP:20220916T003527
DTSTART;TZID=GMT:20220916T003527
LAST-MODIFIED:20220916T003527
ORGANIZER;CN=test@abc.com:mailto:test@abc.com
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Test Sample custom
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:22952194683567780405841975923477846064353531523395013511058263369055782053751411479304767882751767652242148467737398
X-EXTRAPARAMS:Test Extra Param

X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In this we have set `X-EXTRAPARAMS` value which needs to be shown to user in his calendar but the value is not displayed to the user in his invite.
How can we set the same so that it is displayed to the end user in his calendar?

Answer (score 0):

No calendar app will process a header it knows nothing about. If you want to reliably show something to an end user, it has to be either `DESCRIPTION` or `SUMMARY`.

Comment: DESCRIPTION works fine but if NOTE is added in the above like NOTE:TESTING NOTE..This is still not displayed to end user..What is the exact property ?

Comment: Sorry, it need to be `SUMMARY` for the subject and `DESCRIPTION` for the body. You can also use `X-ALT-DESC` to set HTML body (e.g., `X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body>test</body></html>`